# What can be done about this fireplace

Tags: drywall, fireplace, design, renovation, diy-vs-pro

[image: ventless gas fireplace]

This looks terrible! I want a fireplace but this just looks wrong to me.  It goes all the way to the ceiling which is 2 stories. 
 Can it be removed leaving just the fireplace and mantle?  Does anyone know the reason for this non functional  chimney?   It does not extend into the attic or exterior of the home.

Comment: Why do you think it's non-functional? Have you looked up in there to confirm that your fireplace has absolutely no means to be vented?

Comment: It is an assumption based on several observations.  1. It does not go past the ceiling. It doesn't extend into the attic nor is there any exterior vent on the roof. 2. I had a contractor walk through to look at something else and he also questioned  the training behind it. 3. The home was built in 1997 and there are several cabin monoxide detectors throughout the home (but no fire detectors oddly).  

I suppose i could be wrong, but I won't be able to do any more investigating for a few days.

Comment: Can what be removed? The walls around the chimney? Is the fireplace wood, gas, or electric? Is there a vent on the side of the house?

Comment: It's a gas fireplace.   That isn't a chimney.  Contractor and I believe it's a faux chimney.

Comment: And no. There is no vent

Comment: @Jess A lot of CO detectors are also smoke detectors. It's a little surprising that they would use CO for all of them, but you may want to verify exactly what those are - smoke detectors are an easy part of fire safety! (separate issue / question though!)

Comment: Yeah they are only CO2.  So much of this home is a mystery.   Inspectors verified that they are no smoke detectors.

Comment: If it is not vented (it should be) you need CO monitors. Many contractors put in Faux chimneys to make the fireplace look real. If I remember correctly the space above the unit requires 32-40"  or the ones I installed many years ago required that much space above. whatever is done you really need a vent for your health and that of your family.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!   are ventless gas fireplaces not as safe as they are marketed to be? Or do you think this is not the ventless type and was installed incorrectly 20 years ago?

Comment: Well... you might want to do some exploratory work to make sure there isn't some exhaust vent that "sneaks" under the second-floor subfloor to an output on some back wall or the like.   Only an  all-electric has nothing to vent and nothing to worry about (other than electrical overheats)

Comment: It's really a 1.5 story home. The 2nd floor is only on the front side of the house so the ceiling in this room is vaulted and open to the 2nd floor above. You can see the bannister there. I can walk into the attic space behind the fireplace which is over the dining room (the opposite side of that wall is the dining room which has an 8ft ceiling).  What should i be looking for?  Could you describe it please?